# Swift wait for comparison sort to complete

Tags: swift

Normally in Swift I understand how to wait for an asynchronous call to complete and then I can use a completion handler to continue on completion.

However, with sort using comparators in Swift, there is no sign that the sort has completed, so I do not know when to continue. Eg,

```
channels!.sort(comparator: { (c1, c2) -> ComparisonResult in
 ... 
//what do I call here to know that this completed?
}
```

Using a dispatchgroup.wait() seems like this wouldn't work either since the wait might be triggered before completion as well. Ideas welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This call is synchronous so you can put your code after the last line to use the sorted array.

```
channels!.sort(comparator: { (c1, c2) -> ComparisonResult in
 ... 
//what do I call here to know that this completed?
}
// channels is sorted over here
```